# Imported Class not recognized in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, cropperjs

I'm trying to add Cropperjs through CDN into a project I'm doing. The issue I'm having is that when I try to instantiate a new instance of the Cropper Object, VSCode doesn't color it as a class; it colors it as if it were a Function.

When I try to load the page, and the function gets called, I get an error in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Cropper is
> not defined at FileReader.reader.onload (common.js:180)

My code where i try to call it is:

```
$("#filePhoto").change(function(){ //TODO Check with arrow function?
  if(this.files&& this.files[0]){ //check there's one item in the array
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e)=>{
        var image = document.getElementById('imagePreview');
        image.scr= e.target.result;
        
        if(cropper !== undefined){
            cropper.destroy();
        }
        
        cropper = new Cropper(image,{
            aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
            background: false
        });

    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
  }
})
```

I do not understand why it's not working.  When I check Sources in the Browser DevTools, Cropper's JS and CSS files are loaded properly.

Thanks in advance for any insight on this...

PS: Added Test Code in https://pastebin.com/aMge1GTb

Comment: Where you imported Cropper.js?

Comment: Please provide enough (but not more) code for us to be able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I imported it via script in my html (a pug file) using the following lines:

 script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropper/4.1.0/cropper.min.js')

link(rel="stylesheet", href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropper/4.1.0/cropper.min.css")

It's weird because that's what CropperJs documentation says is needed for it to work.

Comment: https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper <= you are using this version, not the non-jquery version.  You can see this by going to your source file in the CDN and seeing the reference at the very top.

Comment: @Taplar thanks for the response... Now it does not throw the errow, but neither the image, nor the cropper are being rendered... I'll check that out, but your comment was really helpful... didn't realize I was using the wrong version.

Comment: @trincot I've added all the code needed for what i want in the pastebin link in the post. Now it is not throwing an error, but the image is not being displayed by the filereader...

Comment: So then your question is not right, because you focus on the Class not being recognised...